# Rails 4: Relations with 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Having a bit of a problem, wonder if you guys could help me out.

I have 3 models:

An `app` which belongs to a `service` and a `platform`

A `service` that has many apps

I'm looking to find the correct way to use a relation to find the services that a platform has.

I'm unsure how to do this. I've looked into has_and_belongs_to_many with no cigar.

Wonder if anyone could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into the `has_many :through` relation...

Comment: Hey Arup, darn I'm stupid! Missed out the has_many. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible

**1. app**

```
belongs_to :service
```

**2. service**

```
has_many :apps
```

Not sure about the platform though. An app has many platforms that runs on ? Be careful that :through is a relationship that has to do with both tables, so If platform is the "third" table it makes sense, otherwise not.